# How to get difference in time using Carbon in Laravel

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I want to get the difference of time between now and subscription_endtime which I am fetching from the database. I am using the following code

```
    $subscription_endtime = DB::table('subscriptions')->where('user_id', $user_id)->value('subscription_endtime');
    $today = Carbon::now();
    $totalDuration = $subscription_endtime->diffInSeconds($today);
    return $totalDuration;
```

I am getting the following error

> "Call to a member function diffInSeconds() on string".

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like *subscription_endtime* isn't a carbon object. You can parse it from Carbon

```
$subscription_endtime = DB::table('subscriptions')->where('user_id', $user_id)->value('subscription_endtime');
$subscription_endtime = Carbon::parse($subscription_endtime); // add this line
$today = Carbon::now();
$totalDuration = $subscription_endtime->diffInSeconds($today);
return $totalDuration;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$today = Carbon::now(); //returns todays date and time at this particular second
$from = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', $subscription_endtime);//returns the time fetched from the database as a Carbon Object

$diff_in_seconds = $today->diffInSeconds($from);//returns the difference between $today and $from in seconds
print_r($diff_in_seconds );//prints the difference
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.